# How to get HTML autocompletion for custom web components in an Angular project?

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, typescript-typings, lit

I have an Angular project that uses custom elements (web components) created with Lit. The web components are working correctly, but I am not getting autocompletion for them in my IDE (Pycharm or VS Code). How can I get autocompletion for these custom elements in my IDE?

What I have tried so far:

- My web component has an exported declaration file
- I have tried to manually add a declaration with the exported attributes and made sure it was included in my tsconfig
- I have used the custom element's tag with the is attribute set correctly in my Angular component's HTML template.

My web components work correctly in the project, but I am not getting autocompletion for them in my IDE.
I also have tried restarting my IDE.

What can I do to get autocompletion for my custom elements in my IDE?